# Android SDK (Nexus 5X API28 x86) stopping at preparing for setup

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I've recently picked up the Android SDK and I'm attempting to configure an SDK to test programs and maybe do some basic Java app programming on. My problem is that it apparently won't finish its setup. Apart from the freeze, that the start button is grayed out and I do not have access to the Google Play store. I do have access to the Google Play Music and Movie stores.

My main issue with testing any apps to confirm that this would be workable for development is that I have no access to the main Google Play store. I'd like access to it so that I can see how these emulated test devices handle them in comparison to my test apps.

I've provided screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the "Preparing For Setup" bug in several emulator images recently, I'm not doing anything with Play. Think it's a separate issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Download and use the Play System Images for your emulators. They come packaged with the full Play Store.

Open the SDK Manager > Check "Show Package Details" > find the Play System Image for your desired API. Then create an emulator using that image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the prompt answer. I tried the solution you mentioned and that worked out. I had to use the Nexus 5 in the device list but it worked.

Comment: Thanks. I had an issue though: the AVD manager would not recognise the "Play" image, only the "APIs" one.  That is, when I created the device, the SDK version 28 was not listed as an option. Clicking on the "download" option downloaded the "Google APIs" version. So I created the AVD with that, then I modified the "config.ini" and "hardware-qemu.ini" changing the image paths from "google_apis" to "google_apis_playstore".