# Trying to get a rooted Android image in Android Studio with Google Play

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio and it seems that I can only either get an image that allows me to run `adb root` to get a root shell and doesn't support Google Play, or one that supports Google Play and cannot run `adb root` because of it being in production mode.

I've taken suggestions from here: [Android SDK (Nexus 5X API28 x86) stopping at preparing for setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52427106/android-sdk-nexus-5x-api28-x86-stopping-at-preparing-for-setup) and installed "Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image" as shown below:

[image: Google Play Enabled]

However, when I go to create a new image, I'm selecting Pixel 2 (with Google Play next to it):

[image: Pixel 2 selected]

and on the next screen, I'm not quite sure if I'm supposed to select one or the other, but I have tried a few with no luck.

[image: Recommended tab]
[image: x86 tab]

When I install Pie from the Recommended tab with Google Play, I can't establish a root shell. However, when I run it from the x86 tab with Google API, I can establish a root shell but cannot get Google Play working.